# Patching a Solaris flar archive

Tags: solaris, solaris-zones

I have a Solaris flar archive of an old Solaris 10 environment, now I'm not allowed to update the running system in any way so would like to be able to:

1. Extract the flar archive somewhere (without installing it)
2. Apply some Solaris patches to the extracted archive.
3. Repackage the flar archive
4. Use the flar archive to setup a branded zone.

Why do it this way? Well because I need a set of minimum patches to get the darned thing to work as a branded zone.

I know how to do step 4 if I ever get to it.

Comment: it's not possible to restore the flar to temporary hardware?

Comment: Unfortunately not, to add to the complications it's all at a remote site with no additional hardware other than the already running environment and the host to run the branded zones - plus no bandwidth to bring the flar back to another location. Otherwise that is exactly what I would have done.

Comment: can you violate assumption #0 and split the hopefully-mirrored disks in order to apply the patches on the split disk, then re-create a flar of that split disk, then reintegrate it? (insert hand-waving here)

Comment: Mirrored disks - unfortunately not. Yes, it's a mess but not of my doing. I'm just trying to bail it out before it bails out! No swap or other disk to re-purpose either :-(

Comment: Is the old Solaris 10 env still up? If yes, you could go via Boot Enviroment, maybe?

Answer (score 1):

Building on @ludiegu's comment:

1. Create a new boot environment using [`lucreate`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19253-01/817-5505/lucreate-16/index.html).
2. Patch the boot environment as needed
3. Mount the new boot environment with [`lumount`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23823_01/html/816-5166/lumount-1m.html).
4. [Create a flash archive](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18752_01/html/821-1912/flashcreate-66.html) from that boot environment, using the mount point from `lumount` as the root path for the `flarcreate` command.

Also, see [this PDF](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/server-storage/solaris/solaris-live-upgrade-wp-167900.pdf).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but I don't have my notes handy for the 2 or 3 cmds.

For step #1:  You need to break apart the archive and the information from the flar archive.  `flar info` and `flar split`?  You can then extract the cpio'd data with `cpio`.  Then `patchadd -R <dir>`, and then recreate the flar.